# Shortcut for applying a command between the last two marks

Tags: mark

When I first started using Vim 10 years ago, I found myself typing

```
:'a,'fs/target/replacement/g
```

a lot. I was used to using `'a` and `'f` as my go-to marks. So I also had this in my `.vimrc`:

```
map qq :'a,'f
```

Are there any special kinds of marks in Vim that act more like "quick" or "temporary" marks, accompanied by a shortcut or notation that means "the last two quick-marks"?

I looked through the documentation on marks but did not see any. Does anyone have a more elegant shortcut than mine?

Answer (score 3):

Using 2 marks to operate on the text between those lines is the 'vi'-compatible way of the more modern and (literally) visual way of operating in Vim (and probably why visual mode was invented in the 1st place): visually select a range with whatever means (motion, text-object), then start your ex command, which operates line-wise: when you hit `:`, you will see those two quick marks automatically inserted before the `:` (the start and the end marks of the visual selection).

Quick access to "the last two quick-marks" in this case would translate to "restoring the last visual selection", which can be accomplished with `gv`.

And now for the funny part: if you really want it, you can *explicitly* set those two marks (`<` and `>`), manually, using `m<` and `m>`, as with any letter-based mark. I.e. you don't need to go to visual mode for that; then, either use `gv` to restore that selection and start your ex command, or manually insert `:'<,'>some-ex-command-here` to (similarly) operate on that line range. In another words, visual marks can operate exactly as in your request (quick or temporary marks that can be set - a pair of them), with the advantage of also allowing a more visual way of assignation.

So, maybe this mapping, to `ex`ecute on a selection:

```
noremap g: gv:
```

Comment: Also note that `:*` is an abbreviation for `:'<,'>`

Comment: That's interesting (and I can't find where it is documented).

Comment: Yeah, difficult to find: `:help cpo-star`

Comment: Odd, `m<` and `m>` don't work for me. `'<` says _"E20: Mark not set"_.

Comment: Is it too old? `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jun 12 2009 07:08:36)`

Comment: I think the date speaks for itself :) (Newest version is Vim 8.0, October 2016)

Comment: @AndrewCheong Yes that is too old. I think settable marks for the visual selection was in a late 7.3 patch